# Insert table record with auto generate foreign id

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table called `DUTY` (columns: `dutyid, dutyname, staffid`) and a table called `STAFF` (columns: `staffid, staffname`)

In order to be fair, each of the staff will be auto assigned to each duty entry (record). So what should I do whenever I would like to insert a duty entry, it will auto assign the `staffid` (sequential) for it.

Example

- staffid : 1 staffname: Jack
- staffid : 2 staffname: Mary

So when I insert a new entry (first entry) for duty, it will auto insert `staffid = 1` for duty table. For second entry, `staffid` will be 2.

And for the following entry, it will keep looping the `staffid` sequentially.

Desired answer:

```
dutyid   dutyname   staffid 
  1      cleaning     1 
  2      cleaning     2 
  3      cleaning     1 
  4      cleaning     2 
  5      cleaning     1 
  6      cleaning     2 
  7      cleaning     3       new staff
  8      cleaning     1 
  9      cleaning     2 
 10      cleaning     3
```

Can anyone show and explain to me what I should do in my stored procedure...
Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to insert a value that was auto-generated in another table?

Comment: What do you expect to happen as the `STAFF` table grows?  It is always a good idea to include sample data, in tabular form, and your desired results in the question.

Comment: The questions I have ask above is just an example. Branko, yes I want it to auto generate the staffid foreign key whenever I insert new duty record. HABO, I expect it will keep looping with the additional of staff entry. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
select * from duty;

Declare @dutyname varchar(20)='cleaning'
Declare @staffid int
Declare @maxstaffid int

select @staffid=staffid from duty
where dutyid=
(select max(dutyid) from duty);


select @maxstaffid=max(staffid) from staff;

print @maxstaffid;


insert into duty (dutyname, staffid)
select @dutyname,
case
  when @staffid=@maxstaffid then (select min(staffid) from staff)
  else (select min(staffid) from staff where staffid>@staffid)
end ;

select * from duty;
```

Comment: You can use any @dutyname.

Comment: I did try it and it works well, what if I have 2 column instead of staffid, that are staffAssigned and staffWorked which both of these columns are refer to staffid too. So how can I declare the staffAsigned in the 5th line that you have written above? Thanks

Comment: I did not understand "which both of these columns are refer to staffid too".Kindly give the actual schema.

Comment: Staff table(staffid, staffname) contains staff details and it is the FK for Duty table(dutyid, dutyname, staffAssigned, staffWorked), extra columns named StaffAssigned and StaffWorked added for curbing the problems of staffAssigned might not able attend the work, so it will replaced by StaffWorked. This means that both StaffAssigned and StaffWorked are actually point to the FK(staffid) to knows that who are those staffs been assigned and worked. I would like to know that how should I do in my stored procedure in order to declare StaffAssigned=staffid for auto generate. Thanks

Comment: If staff assigned is not available,  then work is assigned to other employee. How, is StaffWorked selected ?

Answer (score 0):

See [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cfce1/12)

This query will return the next staff number and loop back to the fist one

```
SELECT max(staffid) FROM 
(
  SELECT top 1 staff.staffid
  FROM staff, (
   SELECT top 1 staffid
   FROM duty
   ORDER BY id DESC
  ) d
  WHERE staff.staffid > d.staffid
  Order by staff.staffid
 UNION
  SELECT top 1 staffid 
  FROM staff
  ORDER BY staffid
) x
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, is to use the duty table to get the least used staff member assigned next.

```
select top 1 staffID,count(*)
from duty
group by StaffId
order by 2
```

Now, as each new duty gets inserted, the staff member with the least number of duties get the new duty insert.   Of course, if staff members are assigned infrequently, this solution could cause a problem that when a new staff member is added, he gets all of the duty assignments for a while.

Comment: sorry i am new here, I might need further explanation, how about if i just want to keep looping without considering the least used staff member. And can you show me the stored procedure format with explanation for doing this. or any other format which it might works. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SCOPE_IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) to get the last auto generated id:

```
declare @last_id int

-- assumes staffid is an auto generated key (identity)
insert into STAFF (staffname) 
values ('JACK')

select @last_id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

insert into DUTY (dutyid, dutyname, staffid)
values (1, 'duty-name-jack', @last_id)

insert into STAFF (staffname) 
values ('MARY')

select @last_id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

insert into DUTY (dutyid, dutyname, staffid)
values (2, 'duty-name-mary', @last_id)
```